# Extract pdf / image from doc88 Flash viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, encryption, download, flash

doc88.com uses some kind of encryption to protect pdf files. I used Chrome developer tools and found that it loads .ebt file. I think its encrypted Pdf / Swf file.

I found the following reply [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/98393/is-it-possible-to-get-the-text-of-a-document-being-shown-by-the-flash-player) but i still cannot download the pdf file. Can anyone help ?

> Okay. The encryption that docin.com uses is absolutely unknown to me,
>   but I determined that doc88.com probably uses software from
>   cryptbot.com, through I was unable to extract the key: it's probably
>   buried deep into the flash viewer. –  whitequark

Comment: maybe key is http://www.doc88.com/dsp.php

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/doc88-download It saves a PNG of each page, which could then be converted to a PDF or other format as a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get a pdf file from www.doc88.com:

1. Go to the website of the document of interest and **load every page of the document you want to extract** by hovering over them for a few seconds (to do this faster, zoom out). This will save the pdf in the cache of Chrome. By default, not all pages are loaded in the first place.
2. Right click anywhere on the screen and select "Print...".
3. Print to PDF.
4. Use a tool to crop the parts of the page that do not belong to the PDF. For instance, in Linux you can use [pdfjam](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjam). More examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124692/command-line-tool-to-crop-pdf-files).
5. Use an OCR program to reconvert the image to text. Quality is not assured. Some utilities for Linux [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR).